# Exception on php artisan migrate Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054]

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I created a database on the terminal and mysql version is 8.0.21 Homebrew. I access the database using TablePlus. However when I tried to migrate the database after creating the database it gave me the following error.

[image: Error on terminal]

My php version is 7.3.11. Any guidance towards using the right resources to be able to migrate successfully are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following commands,

`brew update`

`brew upgrade`

and it downloaded and updated the php and mysql version.